# Strict regex python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to fetch below string from a content, which is part of a table row extracted from pdf.

```
$import re
$re.findall(r'\s\d+\s[Trillion$]+', '2 4334 Rigid Tall 54 Trillion somr text')
$[' 54 Trillion']
```

This is valid, but if string contains some invalid characters it returns empty list, instead I want it should throw an error.

```
$re.findall(r'\s\d+\s[Trillion$]+', '2 4334 Rigid Tall 5&_4 T×rillion somr text')
$[]
```

But it shouldn't throw an error if the text doesn't exist at all

Comment: what do you mean by invalid characters?

Comment: I meant special characters

Comment: okay so you want it to raise error if there are special characters no mater if it also has a match some where in the string?

Comment: @moghya - Yes, But should throw an error if those special characters occurs in that particular string eg( ' 5$4 Tri@llion')

Comment: maybe we have to write two regexes one that you have wrote and another to check if there's special character in between of `\d+[Trillion$]`,

then apply findall on our string with these two regexs according to result throw error

Comment: Your existing pattern is completely wrong, it does not match the text in your question.

Comment: @COLDSPEED yes it has to be `\d+\sTrillion`

Comment: @trex i have come up with something please check here http://pythonfiddle.com/demo-for-strict-regex-python

Comment: Wonderful @moghya, Thank you very much, Much appreciated.
One more quick question - can we check for exact word as well i.e. "Trillion" if that word has typo let us say "Trilllioon", it should raise an error

Comment: @trex well its quite simple just change the character set between all the letters in `Trillion` from `[@#$%^&+=]` to `[A-Za-z@#$%^&+=]` .

If my answer has solved your problem please be generous to accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: @moghya - Wonderful worked like a charm. Accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex `\s\d+\s[Trillion$]+` has one problem that it is using a character class `[...]` where each character is matched individually. So `[Trillion$]+` will also match `TTTT` or `$$$$$` also.

You need to remove character class and also use `.search` instead of `.findall` as in following examples:

```
import re

input = ['2 4334 Rigid Tall 54 Txrillion somr text', '4334 Rigid Tall 54 Trillion somr text']

reg = re.compile(r'\b\d+\s+Trillion\b')

for s in input:
   res = reg.search(s)
   if res:
      print "Matched:", res.group(0), "::", s
   else:
      print "Didn't Match:", s
```

**Output:**

```
Didn't Match: 2 4334 Rigid Tall 54 Txrillion somr text
Matched: 54 Trillion :: 4334 Rigid Tall 54 Trillion somr text
```

[Code Demo](https://eval.in/982844)

Comment: Can we detect the invalid text with your solution?, I'd like  to raise an exception along with the invalid text that failed to match. As moghya has done in his print statement (i.e `print('raise error here beacause ',result_b)`)

Comment: I've updated code to throw error and have also included a code demo.

Answer (score 1):

I have created two reg-ex patterns

1. For matching exact result as we want
2. For matching results that have may or may not have special characters

We get results from both reg-x and dependent on the count of results we raise error.
Please check below code and demo [here](http://pythonfiddle.com/demo-for-strict-regex-python)

```
import re

def process(text):
    result_a = re.findall(r'\d+\sTrillion',text)
    result_b = re.findall(r'[@#$%^&+=]*\d+[@#$%^&+=]*\d*\s[@#$%^&+=]*T[@#$%^&+=]*r[@#$%^&+=]*i[@#$%^&+=]*l[@#$%^&+=]*l[@#$%^&+=]*i[@#$%^&+=]*o[@#$%^&+=]*n[@#$%^&+=]*',text)
    if len(result_a)==0 and len(result_b)>0:
        print('raise error here beacause ',result_b)
    else:
        print(result_a)


tests = ["2 4334 Rigid Tall 54 Trillion somr text","2 4334 Rigid Tall +54 Tri+llio@n somr text"]
for test in tests:
    process(test)
```